# How do I get the download log from the chrome driver?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm not sure how and where the logs for files received from the web are stored. Is there a location where the log for the download file is saved?
Or how can I log files I received from the web?
Thank you for reading this.

> ```
> options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
>     options.add_argument("user-data-dir=\\test_profile")
>     options.set_capability("loggingPrefs", {'performance': 'ALL'})
>     
>     service = ChromeService(executable_path=driver_path)
>
>     driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, chrome_options=options)
>     driver.implicitly_wait(3)
>     driver.get(change_url)
> ```

Comment: If that's what you mean, you can set the log file path by enriching the statement:
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, chrome_options=options, service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=C:\\temp\\out.log"])

Comment: I tried it, but the log file is not created at that location.